# Scheduling a task with specific delay and run by multiple nodes

Tags: java, executorservice

I have a Schedular which runs after 60 secs when i invoke my API. Now the scenario is after i invoke my API if my server goes down then this schedular task will not execute. So I want to pick it up from the same point where it has left when the server came up. Or the second scenario is if one node is down second node should take up the schedular task. How can i achieve this?

Any suggestions would really help.

Thanks in advance

```
@PostMapping("/books")
private int saveBook(@RequestBody Books books) {
    System.out.println("Before " + new Date().toString());
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledThreadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    scheduledThreadPool.schedule(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("After " + new Date().toString());
        }
    }, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("M out");
    return books.getBookid();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

General way to achieve this is to use an async medium like a queue.

You send the task need to be done to queue and has another component listen and execute the task.

One less standard way is to store task in DB, has specific component to scan the DB, take the task, marking that task is processing, execute the task. After certain timeout, other node may pickup the processing task and re-execute it

Comment: Could you please share some reference?